# Does DNS impact internal server settings?

Tags: dns-servers, azure

I have a website which I've made an image from and loaded that image onto two VM's - each configured exactly the same.

One site is configured with my domain - mydomain.com - with the A record pointing to it.

The other is accessed by the Azure VM url - mydomain.cloudapp.net.

Testing performance of these sites using GTMetrix - and several other tools - the Azure url always performs much faster which could be a DNS issue. The strange thing is that the problems reported are gzip, combine images using sprites, defer javascript parsing, avoid bad requests, minify css, and leverage browser caching.

When I change the dns A record and point it to the faster, errorless, system, the problems follow it.

Not sure why these types of issues would be impacted by DNS.

Thanks!

Comment: Should not be. DNS only ties the domain name to an IP address- nothing more. There are slow DNS servers of course. Other than that, it could be caching of some sort. Not DNS.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too Tnoc…I usually run into problems with caching.